Inverse collider in unity possible?
I am making a game where I do not want the player to go outside a certain boundary. I can create a few box colliders and define that boundary. But a sphere collider with a inverse type would be much better for my superman style game. Where I can attach a sphere collider to an empty game object and scale it. But doing so will push the player outside of the collider. That's why I need somewhat inverse effect so that player stays only inside of it. It does not exist but experienced people might have done something similar. So I would like to know if it is possible and if so how.
TIA.

Probably would have to use a concave mesh collider with a custom double sided sphere mesh ...

Alternatively I could imagine a soft limit and rather use a big trigger sphere collider, use OnTriggerExit and apply some forces to push the player back into the allowed volume/area until it is fully within the sphere again

There is no Inverse collider that can do this because colliders works moving each other collider in a direction that is usually calculated with the center of the collider.
BUT you can put some gameObject that tracks the player and some radius of boundary.
So if the tracked object (player) goes outside of radius is forced its position to be inside of radius.

Right. Unity's primitive colliders are always convex as they represent a mathematical volume. Non-convex MeshColliders are purely surface colliders and are more expensive to calculate. A MeshCollider could be used with a custom mesh, but using a bunch of box colliders would be more flexible and less taxing.

Using a bunch of boxes doing a mesh of a sphere dinamically has its pros and cons against a tracker.
Sphere of boxes:

Its usually more efficient
works better with phisics as it uses real colliders


has either low resolution or bad efficiency
complex code to generate sphere out of boxes

Tracker:

its efficient
keeps code simple


may have weird interaction with the movement and phisics

